# Run water from under deck to backyard

Tags: plumbing, water, outdoor, gardening

I have an Outdoor Water Faucet right under the deck which is very hard to reach. So far I have connect a 50ft water hose there permanently but I always shut off from the faucet because it's leaking water a bit at the connection and I don't want to winter freeze to crack the connection.

I need to redo this system. My plan is to have: (1) drip irrigation system and (2) a new faucet somewhere outside the deck.

I have a few questions:

1. The current faucet is copper. What is the best way to connect something permanently to it and have a 2-way spliter?
2. Which material should I choose to run a new external faucet outside the deck? I try to avoid removing the old faucet (may involve breaking the wall?!). I am thinking if there is some PVC that one end can screw in the faucet and the other end would connect to a new faucet? But PVC can't connect to metal faucet, right?
3. What kind of drip irrigation is best for summer and winter (sometime freezing in Pacific Northwest)? I was thinking of doing this http://www.thisoldhouse.com/toh/how-to/overview/0,,1088902,00.html

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try PEX. And wichever way you are doing you will still need to to close the water at the old valve or put a valve on the line before exiting to avoid freezing the outside pipes.

Comment: But how do I go about having another valve connecting to another valve? What would the solution look like?

Comment: Put threaded female to Pex adapter and then put a new valve at the end of the Pex where its convienient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of wallis the faucet mounted into? I was goingnto recommned a new pipebbut if you said you may break the wall that's a no go. For the winter you shoulsnt have to worry about freezing as long as you shut off the water to the facuet ibside the house and drain out your hose. I belive they do make pvc to copper but ibwould recommend just using copper and putting in inside a piece of pvc for extra protection. I apologise but I don't know anything about drip irrragation however

Comment: For outdoor specific, is there a benefit of using copper? Except that it is harder / heavier? The current valve at the wall is straight up copper inside the wall. Its not a simple task to just remove and hook copper into it.